# Receiving FD_CLOSE when there should be FD_READ

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock2

I have a strange problem on one of my clients workstation. I have a simple application that exchanges some data over network between two endpoints.

Basically the transaction goes like this:

1. Client A listens for incomming connection
2. Client B connects to A and sends some data
3. Client A read this data for further processing

Now the strange part is that client A does not receive whole data (sometimes it a part of buffer sometimes it is empty).

The A client uses WSAEventSelect function and waits for FD_READ to read data sent by B and for FD_CLOSE to detect disconnection.

Usually ( everytime except this one particular client) the FD_READ is signaled, data is processed and after that FD_CLOSE is signaled and all is fine, but here instead FD_READ i receive FD_CLOSE.

Can someone tell me how this is possible? Another thing is that program was working fine for about a year and suddenly it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the strange part is that client A does not receive whole data (sometimes it a part of buffer sometimes it is empty).

There's nothing strange about that, that's how TCP works, except that you will never receive zero bytes in blocking mode.

> Usually ( everytime except this one particular client) the FD_READ is signaled, data is processed and after that FD_CLOSE is signaled and all is fine, but here instead FD_READ i receive FD_CLOSE.

Note that FD_READ can be signalled any number of times, not just once. You're not guaranteed to receive an entire message in a single read.

> Can someone tell me how this is possible?

The client has closed the connection.

Comment: "you will never receive zero bytes in blocking mode", yes you will. That is how a graceful disconnect is reported - by `recv()` returning 0.

Comment: I know that FD_READ can be signaled more that once, but why it is not signaled at all and I receive just FD_CLOSE

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course but that's not receiving zero bytes, that's using zero as a sentinel to indicate EOS, and it's only possible *because* you can never receive zero bytes.

Comment: @Brukwa Because there was nothing to read? Presumably the client never sent any data.

Comment: @EJP: the only way you can get an `FD_CLOSE` notification is if either the connection has been closed gracefully or has been lost abnormally. You need to check the error code reported by `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` to differentiate between them. If you are getting `FD_CLOSE` when you are expecting `FD_READ`, then I suspect the connection is being closed abnormally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's exactly what I've been saying. I don't know why your comment is addressed to me. It's the OP who needs the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"An application should check for remaining data upon receipt of FD_CLOSE to avoid any possibility of losing data."

So if the error code associated with the FD_CLOSE notification is 0, you should check to see if you still have data to read, that might be where your missing data is.

If the error code is NOT 0, then there was an error and the missing data is probably lost.